# How to get sum of all max column value

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have an issue get cate and point below.

This is table query

```
-------------------------------------------
id    title    cate    query_id    point   |
-------------------------------------------
1     A        1       1           1       |
2     B        1       1           3       |
3     C        1       1           2       |
4     A        2       2           3       |
5     B        2       2           2       |
6     C        1       2           1       |
--------------------------------------------
```

If I groupby(cate, query) and get max point

```
----------------------------
cate    query_id    point   |
----------------------------
1       1           3       |
2       2           3       |
1       2           1       |
----------------------------
```

but I want to get sum of max poin by cate like this:

```
--------------
cate    point |
--------------
1         4   | 
2         3   |
--------------
```

I hope you could help me.

Comment: I don't understand your expected output.  Can you explain the logic behind it?

Comment: I added logic. Could you please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make an aggregate of an aggregate using a derived-table subquery like this:

```
SELECT cate, SUM(point) AS point
FROM (
    SELECT cate, query_id, MAX(point) AS point
    FROM MyTable
    GROUP BY cate, query_id
) AS t
GROUP BY cate;
```

Comment: Glad to help. Remember on Stack Overflow it is custom to upvote answers that helped you, and use the green checkmark for the answer that solved your problem in the best way.

Answer (score 0):

with this you get the desired result

```
query::groupBy(cate,query_id)->sum(point)
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to **use group by(cate, query) and get cate,query_id,max(point)**.

```sql
SELECT cate, query_id, MAX(point) AS point
FROM demo
GROUP BY cate, query_id
```

[demo on dbFiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6mAEoKRvzyhVP8nR55R44b/2)

Now You want to get **sum of point group by cate from the above query output**.

```sql
SELECT p.cate, SUM(p.point) AS point
FROM (
    SELECT cate, query_id, MAX(point) AS point
    FROM demo
    GROUP BY cate, query_id
) AS p
GROUP BY cate;
```

[demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/6mAEoKRvzyhVP8nR55R44b/4)